# Pass name value pair array to controller as dictionary

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a name value pair array in Javascript (just like form.SerializeArray()) which i want to pass to my controller and receive it as a list of dictionary objects.

is it possible ? If so how do i pass the object  ?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Here is my JS object which i want to pass

```
var ct = $('#frmrpt').serializeArray();
url="MyController/Print";
var vhtml = "<iframe src=" + url + " style='width: 100%; height: 100%' ></iframe>";

$('#repo').html(vhtml);
```

And Here is how i want to receive it at the controller

```
public ActionResult Print( List<Dictionary<string, object>> prms)
```

I use something like below to deserialize json strings

```
public static T DeserializeJSON<T>(string jsonData)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonData))
    {
        //jsonData = jsonData.Replace('"', ' ');
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return serializer.Deserialize<T>(jsonData);
    }
    return default(T);
}
```

Comment: How should we know? Post some code, atleast show the object in question and explain how the controller works and how you intend to do the dictionary stuff ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use json.net to deserialize your collection.

*Controller:*

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
[JsonFilter(Param = "data", JsonDataType = typeof(Dictionary<string,string>))]
public ActionResult Add(Dictionary<string, string> data)
{

}
```

*client:*

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        async: true,
        data:  JSON.stringify(data),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {

        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

        }
    });
```